# Adsense ads not working inside angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, adsense

I'm  trying putting Google Adsense ads inside an Angularjs ng-repeat like below. But its not working

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items"
<div ng-include src="view.getItem($index)"></div>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<div ng-if="$index == 0" google-adsense>
    <ins class="adsbygoogle responsive"
         style="display:inline-block;width:468px;height:60px"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-"
         data-ad-slot=""></ins>
    <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
</div>
</div>
```

I see below error in my console.

```
Uncaught Error: adsbygoogle.push(): All ins elements in the DOM with class=adsbygoogle already have ads in them
```

Is there someway to show adsense ads inside ng-repeat?

Comment: why are you adding same script multiple times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using directive

```
var adSenseTpl = '<ins class="ad-div adsbygoogle responsive" style="display:inline-block;width:468px;height:60px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxx" data-ad-slot="xxxxx"></ins></ins>';

angular.module('reviewmattersApp')
    .directive('googleAdsense', function($window, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        template: adSenseTpl,
        replace: false,
        link: function postLink(scope, element, iAttrs) {
                element.html("");
                element.append(angular.element($compile(adSenseTpl)(scope)));
                if (!$window.adsbygoogle) {
                    $window.adsbygoogle = [];
                }
                $window.adsbygoogle.push({});
        }
    };
});
```

In html side

```
<div  google-adsense>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try creating a function like this in JS file

```
function createAndAppendAdsElement(id, adUnitID) {
    var parent = document.getElementById(id);

    var ele = document.createElement('ins');
    ele.style.display = 'block';
    ele.className = 'adsbygoogle';
    ele.setAttribute('data-ad-client', 'ca-pub-XXXXXXXX');
    ele.setAttribute('data-ad-slot', adUnitID);
    ele.setAttribute('data-ad-format', 'auto');
    ele.setAttribute('data-full-width-responsive', 'true');

    parent.appendChild(ele);

    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
}
```

This method finds a div with provided **ID** and then create a **INS** element and append it to that div.

Call this method on window load as below:

```
window.onload = function () {
    createAndAppendAdsElement('elementOne', 'your_ad_unit_number');
    createAndAppendAdsElement('elementTwo', 'your_ad_unit_number');
    createAndAppendAdsElement('elementThree', 'your_ad_unit_number');
    createAndAppendAdsElement('elementFour', 'your_ad_unit_number');
    createAndAppendAdsElement('elementFive', 'your_ad_unit_number');
};
```